# java chat program (p2p)

Tags: java, p2p

for a project for school i need to write a chat program.

what i have so far:

database users(Username, Password, IPAddress, onlineStatus)
  loginform
  mainChatForm
  registerForm

im able to connect to the database, register users, check online users,...

but now coms the tricky part and here is where im lost. I now need to write the chatprogram itself. i found some tutorials on the internet but they all use server-client. I dont what to do this i want to make it p2p.
i understand i still need to use the serversocket-socket thing. thats why i keep the users IP in the database.

i need some guidance on how to start to build the chat part of my project.

if someone could help me that would be great.

Thanks

DenTilloZie

Comment: This question is far too broad. You should start small (e.g. try opening a connection from one machine to another) and if you run into *specific* problems, the ask about them here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you will need a central server that holds all of the login information, status of users, and their IP addresses. Users can register their IP address at login time.

In order to initiate a chat with somebody, a user will browse the list of online users on the central server, fetch the IP address of the person they want to communicate with, and then make a direct P2P connection to them.

Everything you need to know about actually implementing this is in the API or stackoverflow. If you have more specific questions about implementation you should probably make another more specific question.

Comment: i dont really want a central server. the program i made so far has a list with users (there is a class User that holds all the information) that are online.
the idea really is that there is only a database with all registered users. the program gets the users and UserInfo from the database. when the user click on another user he will be able to start chatting.

Comment: How are other users supposed to know the address of other users? You can't just call up Steve on his phone and ask for his IP address, and IP addresses change. You could store your addresses in the database (but that's still basically a central server).

Comment: at login the ip of the user is checked and saved to the database. so when a user clicks a username the program gets the ip of the selected user from the database. sorry for not making that clear.

its somewhat as you said but not really a central server only a database

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, you can make two threads. One holds a server socket and the other a client socket. The server thread will be listening for new messages from the other peer, while the user thread, can be used to send new messages.